# Avoid looping over visited URLs generated by mongodb and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, cookies

I have a mongodb collection, in which each document is accessible through a specific url.

The goal is to display a random document url to the user, which has not been visited before, until the user has seen all documents in the collection, then the whole collection shall be 'cleared' so it is accessible again.

I have thought about using cookies to achieve it, but I haven't found a way to do it.

The application is built using express for nodejs, with the mongoose module for mongodb.

**Model.class:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    URLSlugs = require('mongoose-url-slugs'),
    AutoIncrement = require('mongoose-sequence')(mongoose),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var dilemmaSchema = new Schema({
    dilemma_title: String,
    red_dilemma: String,
    blue_dilemma: String,
    red_dilemma_votes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    blue_dilemma_votes: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
});


dilemmaSchema.plugin(AutoIncrement, {
    inc_field: 'id'
});
dilemmaSchema.plugin(URLSlugs('dilemma_title'));

module.exports = mongoose.model('Dilemma', dilemmaSchema);
```

**Code snippet from Router:**

```
dilemmaRouter.route('/next')
    .get(function (req, res) {

        Dilemma.count().exec(function (err, count) {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);

            Dilemma.findOne().skip(random).exec(function (err, dilemma) { //This function is supposed to redirect to an unvisited URL, and mark it as visited
                dilemmaID = dilemma._id;

                res.redirect('/' + dilemma.id + '/' + dilemma.slug);

            })
        })

    })
```

**How the database entries are looked up**

```
dilemmaRouter.route('/:id/:slug')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        const _id = req.params.id;
        const _slug = req.params.slug;

        let query = {
            id: _id,
            slug: _slug
        }

        Dilemma.findOne(query, function (err, dilemma) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                if (dilemma === null) {
                    res.redirect('/');
                } else {
                    res.render('index', {
                        dilemma: dilemma
                    })
                }


            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you cycle through documents with an order and then not random, you just can add +X to your current id.

If it's random, you need to store for all users all documents they already have seen. So you need another 'table' in your database, or you need to add a field inside your user model where your store all documents seen.

The 'best' solution is think right now would be to add this field in your user model (or be able to know that IP X already saw document A and B). When your user try to access your page, you get the list of all id for the document you have, remove the id saw by the user, and do a random inside this list.

```
dilemmaRouter.route('/next')
    .get(function (req, res) {

        Dilemma.count().exec(function (err, count) {
           // find all documents 
            User.find({'idUserOrIP' : 'userIPorID'}).exec(function(user) {
                var userListSaw = user.listSaw;
            })
            // create a list with all your document id
            var allDocs = [1...100];
            // remove id already seen (user saw id 1 to 3)
            allDocs = [4...100];
            // random now store the index of the id of the document you want to display
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * allDocs.length);
             // just find your document with the id you just get
            Dilemma.find({'id' : allDocs[random]}).exec(function (err, dilemma) { //This function is supposed to redirect to an unvisited URL, and mark it as visited
                dilemmaID = dilemma._id;

                res.redirect('/' + dilemma.id + '/' + dilemma.slug);

            })
        })
})
```

Comment: Currently i do not have any User Model, since it will mostly be guests visiting my site. But in case i am to make one, how can i then grab a users ip adress and make a user out of that? Also, don't you think this is doable using cookies in some way? To me it just seems like the best choice (if at all possible).

Btw i updated my post with a code snippet of how the urls for the database entries are generated.

Comment: About the ip, you can access it from the `req`. but you can use cookies too, it will work

Comment: Oh, good to know. Do you have an idea for how i could go about doing it with cookies? Is it possible to create url specific cookies? So i for example can just set cookie = 'visited' for all the pages that have been visited.

Comment: inside your user cookies, just store the list of all visited page.  You can use the cookie-parser middleware to handle cookies https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser